# Whenever i am changing this python script to executable file my database file is not connected to this app

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

```
# pylint: disable-all
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QApplication,
    QPushButton,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QHeaderView,
    QGridLayout,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QMenuBar,
    QAction,
    QDialog,
    QAbstractItemView,
    QMenu,
)
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QCoreApplication
import sqlite3


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        self.c = conn.cursor()

        self.setWindowTitle("Shop")

        # Call the setup

        self.initGui()

    def initGui(self):
        self.dialog = QDialog()
        self.dialog.setModal(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.dialog)
        self.dialog.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.vbox = QGridLayout(self.dialog)

        label = QLabel()
        label.setText("Search by Item ID :")
        self.vbox.addWidget(label, 0, 0)
        self.ledit = QLineEdit()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ledit, 0, 1, 1, 3)

        LABELS = [("Item ID :", 3, 0), ("Article No. :", 4, 0), ("Brand :", 5, 0), ("Description : ", 6, 0), ("Company :", 7, 0), ("Company Code :", 8, 0)]
        self.labels = []
        for l in LABELS:
            label = QLabel()
            label.setText(l[0])
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
            self.vbox.addWidget(label, l[1], l[2])
            temp = QLabel()
            temp.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.vbox.addWidget(temp, l[1], l[2] + 1, 1, 3)
            self.labels.append(temp)

        label = QLabel()
        label.setText("Quantity :")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(label, 2, 2)

        self.ledit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.ledit2.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ledit2, 2, 3)

        BTNS = [("Search", lambda: self.search(), 1, 0, 1, 4), ("Save", lambda: self.save(), 2, 0, 1, 2)]
        for btn in BTNS:
            button = QPushButton()
            button.setText(btn[0])
            button.clicked.connect(btn[1])
            self.vbox.addWidget(button, btn[2], btn[3], btn[4], btn[5])

    def save(self):
        try:
            if not self.ledit2.text() or not isinstance(int(self.ledit2.text()), int):
                return self.ledit2.setText("Quantity!")
            for i in range(len(self.labels)):
                if self.labels[i].text() == "" or self.labels[i].text() == "n/a":
                    return
                else:
                    with open("saved.csv", "a") as file:
                        file.write(self.labels[i].text() + ",")
            with open("saved.csv", "a") as file:
                file.write(self.ledit2.text() + "\n")
            self.ledit2.setText(self.ledit2.text() + " <<-- Saved")
        except ValueError:
            self.ledit2.setText("Quantity!")
        finally:
            lines = open("saved.csv", "r").readlines()
            lines_set = set(lines)
            out = open("saved.csv", "w")
            for line in lines_set:
                out.write(line)

    def search(self):
        try:
            results = self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=:id", {"id": self.ledit.text()})
            r = results.fetchone()
            for i in range(len(r)):
                self.labels[i].setText(str(r[i]))
        except TypeError:
            for i in range(len(self.labels)):
                self.labels[i].setText("n/a")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = Window()
    win.show()
    # win.showMaximized()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code

Comment: @CoolCloud can you check now my code is running but the data is not transferred can you tell me what might me the issue

Comment: Try `rows = csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')`  and then loop through rows? Its hard to say without knowing data is in the csv file and the sql statement has to get each value separate.

Comment: @CoolCloud '/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' your_script.py  i have created one database app but whenever i am changing it to exe file the data is not showing. Can you tell me how to include .db file when i change python scrip to executable file

Comment: Not sure, keep the file with you in your directory and you have to send that file with the db to others, and make sure the exe is in the project directory

Comment: @CoolCloud both the script and .db file are in same folder  and i used the same command that last time u provide me to create exe file for tkinter it works apart from it does not connect to my database file

Comment: The code I gave you was for `tkinter`, here your using `pyside`, the db should be connected and work if your having it in the same folder. This was not the original Q of the file, you edited the post to ask a new Q. Its better to ask a new Q.

Comment: @CoolCloud they have banned me from asking new question that’s why i m edit the old question to ask you back the answer

Comment: @CoolCloud can you check I am gettin this error every time I change my .py file to exe it and open it, it shows me errors mention below,

Comment: I dont follow, what your trying to say.